# How to flash diffrent form action field validation error message in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a view where has 2 forms. One for login another for signup. For signup action I have used action

```
Users/add
```

I have given form action in my `login.ctp` like

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user, ['url' => ['action' => 'add']]); ?>
```

In add action I written code

```
public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            }else{

                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            } 
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }
```

Now If I made any validation error , example password match validation error, this error not showing under the field `password`. But I am able to see it form add.ctp.

How I can send this validation error message, from add action to login action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to forward the current action to a different action on the same controller, you can use Controller::setAction()

```
public function add()
{
    $this->setAction('login');
}
```

[doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-another-action-on-the-same-controller)